# Create socket from hostname and port but ::select() indicates no data

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to create a socket using a hostname and port. However, `::select()` implies the socket has no data.

Can someone please help?

Self-contained example below (and Godbolt link).

https://godbolt.org/z/r7G3aczdK

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool isSocketReady(int sockfd)
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);

    tv.tv_sec = 2;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    const int retval = ::select(sockfd, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (retval == -1)
    {
        printf("select() error");
        return false;
    }
    else if (retval)
    {
        printf("Data is available now.\n");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No data within timeout.\n");
        return false;
    }
}

int connectByHostName(const std::string& host, int port)
{
    int sockfd = -1;

    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG | AI_NUMERICSERV;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    const std::string port_str = std::to_string(port);

    struct addrinfo* res{nullptr};
    const int r =  getaddrinfo(host.c_str(), port_str.c_str(), &hints, &res);
    
    if(r < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    for (struct addrinfo* address = res; address != nullptr; address = address->ai_next)
    {
        sockfd = socket(address->ai_family, address->ai_socktype, address->ai_protocol);
        
        if (sockfd < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        int flag = 1;
        setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char*) &flag, sizeof(flag));

        if(::connect(sockfd, address->ai_addr, address->ai_addrlen) < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(isSocketReady(sockfd))
        {
            break;
        }            
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);
    return sockfd;
}

int main()
{
    int sock = connectByHostName("example.com", 80);
    std::cout << sock << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The compiler explorer is unable to connect to any host. It's their policy. Have you fixed the crash?

Comment: Why are you expecting data in the first place? You are connecting to a HTTP server, unless you first send a HTTP request, you will not get anything in response.

Comment: @273K True but it still allows people to play with the code/compile it etc.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I am trying to connect to a websocket URL which I cannot post. I asked earlier but I was advised to create a minimal self-contained example and use example.com as the host, so I have. Is there another websocket domain I could use?

Comment: Ah, classic XY problem then. Anyway, it's the same for a websocket. Websocket is built on top of HTTP. You will not get anything from the server unless you first send a request. Are you actually sending a request?

Comment: `FD_SET(0, &rfds); select(sockfd, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);` - this is an improper code. Please re-read the man select(2) carefully.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli So how do I verify the chosen record (in the loop) has connected correctly?

Comment: @intrigued_66 if `connect` does not return an error then it connected correctly...

Comment: Note that the first parameter of `select` is a bit different on [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select) than is specified on [POSIX](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?select). As a result,  It's easy to follow a tutorial that accidentally tells your program to shoot itself in the face.

Comment: You're calling it wrongly. You need `FD_SET(sockfd, &rfds)` for a start, and the first parameter to `select()` is also incorrect. As is your expectation that the socket will immediately be readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `select()` incorrectly.

You need to change this:

```
FD_SET(0, &rfds);
```

to this:

```
FD_SET(sockfd, &rfds);
```

And change this:

```
::select(sockfd, ...);
```

to this:

```
::select(sockfd+1, ...); // or 0 on Windows
```

That being said, there is no point is using `isSocketReady()` after `connect()` in the code you have shown.  Both HTTP and WebSocket protocols require you to send a request before you can then read any data, but you are not doing that, so the socket will never report as readable.

If you are trying to use `isSocketReady()` to check if `connect()` is successful, then this is wrong too, for 2 reasons:

- you would have to test the socket for *writability* instead of *readability*.
- you are not putting the socket into non-blocking mode (`TCP_NODELAY` is not meant for that purpose), so `connect()` will block the calling thread until the connection is fully established or fails. So you can't use `select()` to check for that condition.  To put the socket into non-blocking mode, you have to do one of the following (depending on which platform your code is running on):

  - create the socket with the `SOCK_NONBLOCK` flag on the `socket()` call.
  - use `fctrl(F_SETFL)` to enable the `O_NONBLOCK` flag on the socket.
  - use `ioctl()` (posix) or `ioctlsocket()` (Windows) to enable the `FIONBIO` option on the socket.